# Who was the Jackson Moore named in the 1838 will of Zachariah Green?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, tennessee, arkansas

[Zachariah Green](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Green-8555)'s [will](https://www.wikitree.com/photo/jpg/Green-8555), dated 13 August 1838, included bequests to:

- "my daughter Peggy Heardin"
- "my Grandson Jackson Moore"
- "my Grand daughter Emily Tesdel"

The will was written in and probated in Sumner, Tennessee.

I am confident that the referenced [Peggy Heardin](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Green-5329) is the woman with an estimated birth year of 1788 who married (1) [Robert Moore on 19 May 1812](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VNCQ-SG8) and (2) [Jonathan Heardin on 14 April 1819](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VNCQ-QZ3).

"Grand daughter Emily Tesdale" is presumably [Emily Moore](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Moore-37081), who was born in Tennessee between 1814 and 1816 and [married Arren Tisdale on 27 August 1835](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QKH3-GCX9) in Sumner, Tennessee.

I have been unable to determine the identity of "Grandson Jackson Moore".

I found these federal census records in various locations for men named Jackson Moore/Moor born in Tennessee during Peggy and Robert Moore's marriage:

- [Jackson Moore (b. ~1817, Tennessee) with Malinda Moore (b. ~1819), Jackson County, Alabama, 1850](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MH59-C5Y)
- [Jackson Moore (b. ~1815, Tennessee) with Sarah Moore (b. ~1832), Fulton County, Arkansas, 1850](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M8W9-M1M)
- [Jackson Moor (b. 1816-1817, Tennesee) with Polly Moor (b. 1817-1818), Gallatin, Illinois, 1870](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M6WM-SPD)

The name "Robert Jackson Moore" appears on an [1836 tax list](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Moore-7716#_note-1) for Spring and Black Townships in Lawrence County, Arkansas. The same page has [a record](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Moore-7716#_note-2) for a Robert J. W. Moore. One question I have is whether the two listings could be for the same man. I consider this lead more promising than the above census records because it is in Lawrence County, Arkansas, where [Peggy and Jonathan Heardin](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M678-KVQ) and [Emily and Orin Tisdale](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M678-BZ4) were known to be living in 1850. Also suggestive are marriage records showing that a man named Robert W. Moore married a woman Abitha [Tisdale](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:N99P-X9W)/[Lisdale](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FQRC-YZS) in Lawrence, Arkansas, on 13 October 1840. Although I have been unable to find any other records for Abitha Tisdale, it seems not unlikely that she is related to Emily's husband Orin Tisdale. It also seems reasonable that the son of a man named Robert would also be named Robert but known by another name during his father's lifetime.

I have collected further information, which can be found on the Wikitree page for [Robert W. Moore](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Moore-7716).

I would like to know:

- the full name of "Grandson Jackson Moore"
- whom he married
- where he lived

Comment: Do you know when/where Robert Moore died and if he left a will, ditto for Peggy?

Comment: On the linked Wikitree page for Robert W. Moore, I have information about a will that I found. I did not find any for Peggy.